# asp.net Redirect To a Particular Page which name is in database column with user authentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user table in which i have a column where i insert Dashboards where i want User to navigate after login. I am not good in asp.net. I want help that how would i navigate to page with user which i have in my database column.

I have done this so far

```
    protected void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAAK-EDOOR;Initial Catalog=db_Security_Model;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[Validate_User]";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", txt_username.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txt_password.Text);
        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        try
        {//txt_username.Text == cmd.Parameters["@Login"].ToString()) && (txt_password.Text == cmd.Parameters["@Password"].ToString())
            if ((cmd.Parameters["@Login"] != null) && (cmd.Parameters["@Password"]!= null))
            {//cmd.Parameters["@PageLink"].ToString()

               // Response.Redirect();
            }
            else
            {
                lbl_invalid.Text = "Ivalid UserName or Password";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
     }
```

Comment: how are you planning on doing this? a button? what have you done so far. I have a solution but, what have you done? Post code.

Comment: yes with the button.

Comment: @MuhamadTaqi you need to navigate to another page with the loggedin user data ?

Comment: Yup. on that page which loggedin user have in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Navigate to the another page using the

```
Response.Redirect("Page_URL");
```

For Passing the Database Column you can use the `Session`

Storing the Value in the Session in Login Page as follows

```
Session["DbcolumnValue"] ="YOur Value coming from DB";
```

In another Page you can access the session value as follows

```
if(Session["DbcolumnValue"]!= null)
{
string value = Session["DbcolumnValue"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: @MuhamadTaqi please upvote the answer , it helps for my effort :)